# It is something wrong in my logic to break lines in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I Have a goal to break lines in 4 to 4 link groups like that in the ReactJS dynamic HTML return:

```
<a>Content</a><a>Content</a><a>Content</a><a>Content</a><br/> 
<a>Content</a><a>Content</a><a>Content</a><a>Content</a><br/> 
<a>Content</a><a>Content</a><a>Content</a><a>Content</a><br/>  
// again and again...
```

My logic is returning:

```
    // WRONG
    <a>Content</a><br/> 
    // OK
    <a>Content</a><a>Content</a><a>Content</a><a>Content</a><br/> 
    // WRONG
    <a>Content</a><br/>
```

Here is the rendering of my ReactJS component:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>         
        {this.state.interiores.map(item =>
          <div>
            <div className="gallery">
              {
                item.fotos
                  .map((foto,index) => {
                    return (
                      <React.Fragment>
                        <a href={`../images/${foto}.jpg`} className="big">
                          <img src={`../images/${foto}_thumb.jpg`} alt="" />
                        </a>
                        // Here is the logic
                        {index % 4 == 0 ? <br /> : ''}
                      </React.Fragment>
                    )
                  })
              }
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
}
```

Comment: What is  <a/>? .

Comment: It is a typo. I edited the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remember that an array index begins at 0. This means that it will only render the break rule after the third item instead of the forth. To fix this you can add 1 to the index.

## Code Sandbox Example

https://codesandbox.io/s/w09jlx65rl

### Example

```js
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.interiores.map(item => (
        <div>
          <div className="gallery">
            {item.fotos.map((foto, index) => {
              return (
                <React.Fragment>
                  <a href={`../images/${foto}.jpg`} className="big">
                    <img src={`../images/${foto}_thumb.jpg`} alt="" />
                  </a>
                  // Here is the logic
                  {(index + 1) % 4 === 0 ? <br /> : ""}
                </React.Fragment>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your logic didn't work. it is separating in 5 to 5 groups instead 4 to 4

Comment: @claudiobitar there is something wrong in your component or data, check my code-sandbox example. Remember that you're mapping the `interiores` array which means when it moves to the next index of the array it will reset the count of the index.

Comment: Thank you! I checked the code and I noticed I was forgotten the  brackets in the logic code

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add `<br>` after 4, you should use the `%` operator.
But pay attention to the fact that `0 % 4 == 0`, therefore after the first item it will add the `<br>`.

You can change your code to check if `index` is greater than 0.

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>         
        {this.state.interiores.map(item =>
          <div>
            <div className="gallery">
              {
                item.fotos
                  .map((foto,index) => {
                    return (
                      <React.Fragment>
                        <a href={`../images/${foto}.jpg`} className="big">
                          <img src={`../images/${foto}_thumb.jpg`} alt="" />
                        </a>
                        // Here is the logic
                        {(index > 0 && index % 4 == 0) ? <br /> : ''}
                      </React.Fragment>
                    )
                  })
              }
            </div>
          </div>
    )}
}
```

Comment: Your logic didn't work. The first <br> entered after 5 links instead 4. The second <br> entered succefully after 4 links